# Is there a way in angular-dart to explicitly notify a view of a modified model?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an app using `@NgController` and the working use case where an UI action triggers a change in the model, which immediately get reflected in the view. The model consists of a list of objects.

What is not working is when the triggered action is starting some asynchron process which eventually modifies the model (adds new elements in the list). The view gets no update.

I guess this works as designed and I am missing something. What pattern should I use in this case?

---

**UPDATE:** Here the minimal code snippet showing the problem:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular bug test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular_bug_test.css">
    <script src="http://lounge-server.jit.su/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body test>
    <h1>Angular bug test</h1>

    <p>The number of element in the list is {{controller.list.length}}</p>
    <input ng-click="controller.addElementSync()" type="button" value="Add Sync"></input>
    <input ng-click="controller.addElementAsync()" type="button" value="Add Async"></input>
    <input ng-click="controller.addElementJsAsync()" type="button" value="Add JS Async"></input>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="element in controller.list">{{element}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="application/dart" src="angular_bug_test.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding dart code:

```
@NgController(selector: '[test]', publishAs: 'controller')
class TestController {

  List<String> list = new List<String>();

  void addElementSync() {
    list.add("${list.length}. element");
  }

  void addElementAsync() {
    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () => list.add("${list.length}. element"));
  }

  void addElementJsAsync() {
    context['io']
      .callMethod('connect', ['http://lounge-server.jit.su:80/'])
      .callMethod('on', ['connect', _onConnect]);
  }

  void _onConnect() {
    Logger.root.fine('connected');
    list.add("${list.length}. connected");
    Logger.root.fine('list.length = ${list.length}');
  }

}
```

When triggering the `Add JS Async` button the console shows the following:

```
FINE : connected
FINE : list.length = 6
```

Unfortunately, neither the `ng-repeat` nor the `{{controller.list.length}}` gets updated.

---

**UPDATE:** The following workaround fix this problem in JS interop (kudos to James)

```
  NgZone _zone;

  TestController(NgZone this._zone);


  void addElementJsAsync2() {
    context['io']
      .callMethod('connect', ['http://lounge-server.jit.su:80/'])
      .callMethod('on', ['connect', _zone.run(_onConnect)]);
  }
```

---

**UPDATE:** The bug is still present in 0.11.0 and `NgZone` has been renamed `VmTurnZone`

Comment: I'm suspecting a bug with js-interop.  To verify: inject NgZone into TestController by creating a constructor: "TestController(NgZone this._zone)" and then calling _zone.assertInTurn() inside _onConnect().    ---- If that assertion throws, there is a bug; a work-around is to wrap _onConnect in _zone.run().   ---- If the assertion doesn't throw, there is something else going on.

Comment: I am very impressed James. From which star are you coming?! ;-)

Comment: @JamesdeBoer could you please suggest a substitute for `NgZone` in latest angular.dart version (0.11.0)? Thanks ;-)

Comment: In 0.11.0, `NgZone` was renamed `VmTurnZone`; the behaviour did not change, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing should work out-of-the-box.  The only tricky part is dealing with lists: in order to detect changes in the list, and custom directives must use `Scope.$watchCollection` to watch the collection.  Normal watches and attribute maps will miss changes in the list.

Built-in directives which deal with lists (e.g. `ng-repeat`) already use `$watchCollection`.

Comment: I am using a list. What do you refer as tricky: detecting changes in the list object or in the elements of the list?

Comment: Yes, it is tricky -- Angular should solve your problem, though. -- What does your view look like?  Are you using ng-repeat to display the list or something else?

Comment: To answer your question, I use ng-repeat. I tried to isolate the problem and it looks like it has something to do with the javascript interop I use to communicate with the socket.io framework. I am updating the question with the code snippet I used.